# android -CompactCalendarView date type

Tags: android, date, calendar

Because I want design about calendar app.
I don't understand why `1477040400000L` is a date type. Why don't use `dd-mm-yyyy` this date type?

```
Event ev1 = new Event(Color.BLUE, 1477040400000L, "Teachers' Professional Day");
compactCalendar.addEvent(ev1);
```

Comment: `1477040400000L` is the number of milliseconds since unix epoch (`1970-01-01T00:00Z`), and it's equivalent to `2016-10-21T09:00Z` (or *October 21st 2016, at 9 AM in UTC*): http://currentmillis.com/?1477040400000

Comment: Oh~ broaden my horizons! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the value `1477040400000L` represents the number of milliseconds since the [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (i.e. 1st January 1970 @ 00:00:00 UTC). As Long Integers typically use much less memory space a String representation of a date (8 bytes vs `String.length` bytes, assuming UTF-8), dates are typically stored as a `long`.

If you absolutely have to use a String representation of a date, you could try this:

```
Event ev1 = null;
try {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
    Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(yourDateAsString);
    ev1 = new Event(Color.BLUE, parsedDate.getTime, "Teachers' Professional Day");
} catch(Exception e) { 
    // dateFormat.parse() could throw a ParseException 
}

if (ev1 != null) {
    compactCalendar.addEvent(ev1);
}
```